# Should I be able have more than one login on the same windows machine use the same VPN?

Tags: vpn, multiple-users

Three or four logins may be active on my windows 10 machine at the same time with remote desktop. I installed NordVPN assuming all users would go through the same VPN. NordVPN technicians say this is not possible. I think they are not configuring the VPN correctly, and the VPN should be applied at the system level rather than the user level. Each time a different person logs in and the VPN turns on, the VPN disconnects for other users. Please say whether all users could go through the same VPN if set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing apples to oranges.  A VPN *can* work in the way you described.  However, *their* VPN does not.  It is not a question of setting it up incorrectly.  They *chose* to implement it that way, therefore it *is* correct.  Why did they make this choice?  Perhaps ease of use, security, or possibly revenue reasons.  Only they can answer that.

Comment: One user should not bump another user off. It is not a good implementation. If NordVPN installs with one TAP connector, then that TAP connector should be available to all users on the machine.

Comment: @subjectivist I am not disagreeing with you.  Nor am I agreeing with you.  However, that is the way it is.  If you dont like their service, then stop using it.